# Custom syntax highlighting in Geany

Tags: syntax-highlighting, geany, kivy

I am trying to create custom syntax highlighting for Kivy '.kv' files in the Geany editor. Although the specific filetype seems irrelavant to the issue I'm having, as any efforts I make at getting syntax highlighting to work for a custom filetype results in a completely non-highlighted file. I believe I have done my homework on this, and nothing seems to work.

I have added the following to ~/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf

```
Kivy=*.kv;
```

I also have a custom type definition file named 'filetypes.Kivy.conf' in ~/.config/geany/filedefs/. I have tried basing this file off several of the stock type definition files in /usr/share/geany/ and the file never gets any syntax highlighting applied in Geany. Right now, just for experimentation's sake, my 'filetypes.Kivy.conf' file looks like this:

```
# For complete documentation of this file, please see Geany's main documentation
[settings]
# default extension used when saving files
extension=kv

# single comments, like # in this file
comment_single=#

[keywords]
# all items must be in one line
primary=size canvas
secondary=pos size

[indentation]
width=4
# 0 is spaces, 1 is tabs, 2 is tab & spaces
type=0
```

This is very loosly based on the stock XML definition file, but like I said I've tried many other stock files. In many cases I only changed the 'extension=' value to kv and still no highlighting was applied, *even though going to Document>Set Filetype in Geany and choosing virtually any random filetype (besides my custom entry) would yeild some sort of highlighting within my .kv file.* This is even the case when using the unmodified contents of a stock definition which otherwise works fine on my .kv file when specifically selected in Geany!

*Also, the Kivy filetype is listed and selected by default in Document>Set Filetype within Geany*, so I must be doing something right here!

I realize this similar question has been asked, but the solutions seem irrelavent to my case, as I've tried every related topic on this and many other sites. **My Geany version is 1.22** and I'm running Arch Linux. This is driving me nuts - any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `lexer_filetype=` property in the `[settings]` section of your filetype file. Working highlighting requires that there is a lexer that could be used for highlighting the .kv-files.

For more info see http://www.geany.org/manual/#lexer-filetype

Comment: Thank you so very very very much jasso! It took some other tweaking before I got it working, but 'lexer_filetype=' was certainly the key to solving this! I will post my Kivy filedefs file as soon as I finish ironing out the keyword wrinkles, so maybe it will help others too! Thank you again jasso!

Comment: Yes please :) where is it?

Comment: @AdamGaskins I'd be interested in that conf file :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three important things to obey:

- the configuration file should be placed in "~/.config/geany/filedefs"
- the configuration file must have the extension ".conf" - otherwise it won't show up at all (the files in "/usr/share/geany/filesdefs", where I copied my base file from, do *not* have a ".conf" extension!)
- you must set the "lexer_filetype" to an existing (presumably builtin) configuration; e.g. "lexer_filetype=Python"