# Yet Another Syntax Highlighting in Geany Issue

Tags: syntax-highlighting, geany, falcon

I am trying to get Geany to recognize syntax highlighting for [Falcon](http://falconpl.org), but have had no luck thus far. I have tried following [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769358/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-geany), but no such luck. I am using version 1.23 of Geany on Fedora 18. The following is my custom `~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Falcon.conf` file:

```
   [keywords]
   primary= <snip>
   identifiers=<snip>

   [settings]
   extension=fal
   comment_single=//
   comment_open=/*
   comment_close=*/
   comment_use_indent=false
   symbol_list_sort_mode=1
   tag_parser=Falcon
   lexer_filetype=Python

   [indentation]
   width=4
   type=0

   # (use only one of it at one time)
   compiler=
   linker=
   run_cmd=falcon "%f"
```

I cut out all the `primary` and `identifiers` since those are rather long, but I do have them included. I have tried using `lexer_filetype=C`, but still no syntax-highlighting. Any suggestions that might help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your filetype_extensions.conf?

Did you check the manual at http://geany.org/manual/#creating-a-custom-filetype-from-an-existing-filetype ?